# How to implement an image gallery in ASP.net webpage without refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, iframe, image-gallery

I am developing a website by using ASP.NET. I want to implement an image gallery thing like showing in this image. When user click a thumbnail image the full resolution image should load.

[image]

So I have a page to save all the information with the images. So when an user upload images I am saving them inside 2 folders ( one folder for the full resolution image and other for the thumbnail images with small resolutions). Also I am saving both paths inside my DB.

So I already loaded bottom panel ( Thumbnail panel ) by using my thumbnail images. I dynamically created imagebuttons for it. There I set imagebutton image URL to my DB URLs. Then I add those imagebuttons to placeholder set in my page. So now its loading. Now problem is how to get my Large preview.

Shall I make an event handler for my Imagebutton and when a user click a image the page will asynchronously refresh and show the image?

Do I need to use Jquery or javascript to do this? Then how?

Is this anything to do with Iframe?

So what is the best way to do this? Am I doing the right thing? I mean loading thumbnaails below and Large scale image top of that or Shall I load high resolution images at first place and do a resize to show them in thumbnail panel?

Thank you very much.

Comment: There is no need for "asynchronous work". Use JavaScript (possibly with the help of jQuery) to manipulate the DOM on a user action such as a click - eg. set the `src` url of the main preview `<img>` element (and the browser will automatically fetch resource and update the image). The large preview URL can be exposed to JS in several ways, including a JS object embedded in the script element or data-attributes of the thumbnails, etc.

Comment: @ user2864740 So I am doing the right thing right? Use image buttons for load the image. Then what I have to do is when I click the imagebutton change the DOM right?

Comment: Sure, sounds like a plan. It may be worthwhile to follow tutorials and look at existing sites, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is on initial load store large-image-url as an attribute on each Imagebutton and onClick event handler use JS to get that attribute and replace img src of the Large preview.

Answer (score 0):

I created something similar while working for my previous company on [this website](http://www.mcdonnell-price.co.uk/). You can view this [JavaScript file](http://www.mcdonnell-price.co.uk/scripts/widashow.js) for the code, but just in case the links die or the site gets updated, the code is below:

#### The Call

```
widashowSetup('[Pipe Delimited List of Small Images]','[Pipe Delimited List of Large Images]','[Path to Left Arrow]','[Path to Right Arrow]');
```

#### JS File

```
//####################################################
//#####  Widashow slideshow image scroller V1.2  #####
//##### Made by Jamie Barker for Wida Group Ltd. #####
//####################################################

//##### SETUP #####
var ThumbnailWidth=111      //SET THIS TO THE WIDTH (+margin/padding) OF THE SMALL IMAGES
var SlideTimer=4000         //THIS IS THE DURATION BETWEEN SLIDE TRANSITIONS, 4000=4 SECONDS
var TransitionTimer=1000    //THIS IS THE TRANSITION DURATION, 1000=1 SECOND
//##### END SETUP #####

var MoveNext
var MovePrev

//Function to decide which way we're moving, and if we're moving now or after a timeout
function CallMove(dir,timer,clear) {
    //Clear the current timers so we're starting afresh
    clearTimeout(MoveNext);
    clearTimeout(MovePrev);

    //If we've specified no timer, just move it now. Otherwise set it to move in the specified time above
    if (dir=='right') {
        if (timer==false) {
            widashowMoveNext()
        } else {
            MoveNext=setTimeout("widashowMoveNext()",SlideTimer);
        }
    } else if (dir=='left') {
        if (timer==false) {
            widashowMovePrev()
        } else {
            MovePrev=setTimeout("widashowMovePrev()",SlideTimer);
        }
    }
}
//Move the images to the right
function widashowMoveNext() {
    //#### Large Images #####
    //Set the current and next image as variables and clone the current image at the end
    var currentImg=$('#widashow-large img:nth-child(1)')
    var nextImg=$('#widashow-large img:nth-child(2)')
    currentImg.clone().appendTo('#widashow-large');

    //Hide the cloned and put it to the bottom of the z-index
    $('#widashow-large img:last-child').css('z-index','0');
    $('#widashow-large img:last-child').hide();

    //Put the next image second in the z-index and make it appear, then fade out the top image
    nextImg.css('z-index','50')
    nextImg.show();
    currentImg.fadeOut(TransitionTimer);

    //#### Small Images #####
    var ImageList=$('#widashow-smallimagelist')
    var FirstImage=$('#widashow-smallimagelist img:first-child')

    //slide the images across by the width each image takes up and move it back when the first image gets put at the end
    ImageList.animate({
        left: '-='+ThumbnailWidth,
        width: '+='+ThumbnailWidth
    },TransitionTimer, function() {
        ImageList.animate({
            left:'+='+ThumbnailWidth,
            width:'-='+ThumbnailWidth
        },0)
    });
    FirstImage.fadeOut(TransitionTimer, function(){
        $(this).appendTo(ImageList);
        $(this).show()
    });

    //Set the new image showing as z-index 100 and remove the image from the top
    setTimeout("$('#widashow-large img:nth-child(2)').css('z-index','100')",TransitionTimer);
    setTimeout("$('#widashow-large img:nth-child(1)').remove()",TransitionTimer);

    //Call it again so it keeps the slideshow moving
    CallMove('right');
}
//Move the images to the left
function widashowMovePrev() {
    //#### Large Images #####
    //Set the current and next image as variables and clone the current image at the end
    var currentImg=$('#widashow-large img:nth-child(1)')
    var nextImg=$('#widashow-large img:last-child')
    //Move the last image to front, hide it but put it's z-index on par with the current top image
    nextImg.prependTo('#widashow-large');
    nextImg.hide();
    nextImg.css('z-index','100');

    //#### Small Images #####
    //Hide the last image and put it to the front of the list
    var LastImg=$('#widashow-smallimagelist img:last-child')
    LastImg.hide();
    LastImg.prependTo($('#widashow-smallimagelist'));

    //Move the images across and fade in the new active small image and fade in the new top large image
    var ImageList=$('#widashow-smallimagelist')
    ImageList.animate({
        left: '+='+ThumbnailWidth,
        width: '+='+ThumbnailWidth
    },TransitionTimer, function() {
        ImageList.animate({
            left:'-='+ThumbnailWidth,
            width:'-='+ThumbnailWidth
        },1, function(){
            LastImg.fadeIn();
            currentImg.css('z-index','50');
            nextImg.fadeIn(TransitionTimer);
            setTimeout("$('#widashow-large img:nth-child(2)').css('z-index','0')",TransitionTimer);
            setTimeout("$('#widashow-large img:nth-child(2)').hide()",TransitionTimer);
        })
    });

    //Call it again so it keeps the slideshow moving
    CallMove('left');
}

//This function sets up the HTML and calls the function to get it moving initially
function widashowSetup(SmallImages,LargeImages,LeftImg,RightImg) {
    //Put the Images into an array so we can loop through them
    var SmallImageList=SmallImages.split('|');
    var LargeImageList=LargeImages.split('|');

    //Put the HTML in for the small images and the navigation buttons
    $('#widashow-small').html('<img class="widashow-nav left" src="'+LeftImg+'" alt="" /><div id="widashow-smallimagelist"></div><img class="widashow-nav right" src="'+RightImg+'" alt="" />');

    //Loop through and insert the large images
    for (var i=0;i<LargeImageList.length;i++) {
        $('#widashow-large').append('<img rel="'+[i]+'" src="'+LargeImageList[i]+'" alt="" />');
    }

    //Loop through and insert the small images
    for (var i=0;i<SmallImageList.length;i++) {
      $('#widashow-smallimagelist').append('<img rel="'+[i]+'" src="'+SmallImageList[i]+'" alt="" />');
    }

    //Start it off by moving it right
    CallMove('right');
}       

//Set up the click events for the navigation
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.widashow-nav.right').on('click', function(event) {
        CallMove('right',false);
    });
    $('.widashow-nav.left').on('click', function(event) {
        CallMove('left',false);
    });
    $('#widashow-smallimagelist img').on('click', function(event) {
        //Set the index for the clicked image
        var ImgIndex=eval($(this).index()+1);

        //Get the number of images
        var ImgTotal=$('#widashow-large img').length
        var ImageList=$('#widashow-smallimagelist')
        var TotalWidth=0

        //Loop through the images, moving them along until we hit the clicked image. Also work out the total width we need to move the images across.
        for (var i=1;i<ImgIndex;i++) {
            $('#widashow-large img:first-child').appendTo('#widashow-large');
            $('#widashow-large img:last-child').css('z-index','0');
            $('#widashow-large img:last-child').hide();
            $('#widashow-large img:first-child').css('z-index','100')
            $('#widashow-large img:first-child').show();
            TotalWidth=eval(TotalWidth+ThumbnailWidth)
            $('#widashow-smallimagelist img:first-child').appendTo($('#widashow-smallimagelist'))   
        }

        //Move the images across the width required
        ImageList.animate({
            left: '-='+TotalWidth,
            width: '+='+TotalWidth
        },100, function() {
            $('#widashow-smallimagelist').animate({
                left:'+='+TotalWidth,
                width:'-='+TotalWidth
            },1, function(){
            })
        });

        //Make it stop moving
        CallMove(false,false);
    });
});
```